# Any tool to convert mysql store procedure to ms sql server store procedure?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, sql-server-2005

I have to migrate database from mysql to ms sql server 2005.I imported table successfully, now i need to convert store procedure written in mysql to ms sql server 2005.i need  to convert a ton of sp so manual conversion is a tedious task, is any tool or simple way to convert sp of mysql to sql server 2005.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54255). It has the ability to migrate Events, Functions, Procedures, Statements, Tables, Views, including the data. SSMA 2005/2008 for MySQL v1.0 is designed to work with MySQL 4.1 to 6.0 and all editions of SQL Server 2005, 2008, and SQL Azure.

Comment: Dear SqlMenace ,
SSMA work only for tables, Not for store procedure.:)

Comment: SSMA now works on Procedures.  I tested it just now.  I've updated the answer to reflect this.